# Code measurements in emperical software engineering: how to plan measurements?

Tags: reference-request, object-oriented

I am talking about a measurement plan for software metrics and I am looking for references.

In emperical software engineering there are code level measurements ("software metrics" that measure, e.g., some property like a paprameter for the redundancy of the code and possibly also a parameter of coupling and cohesion of a large software system.

I have a finished paper with software measurements, but the feedback to me was that the way the measurements parameters are derive can be more, say "systematic" or better put in relationship with the research goals. I am interested to improve my approach for my "future work" (My English is not native, so perhaps I don't use the right terms.)

Are there references on a "measurement plan for software metric" that helps to systematically derive measurement parameters from research goals? (Similar to the [goal question metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GQM) but more focused at academia?) I would like to

Comment: coupling/cohesion metrics are generally not measured a lot except maybe sometimes on very large systems.... are you talking about a measurement plan for software metrics?

Comment: This question is very "meta".  Have you considered telling us what your actual research goals are? Then we might be able to help suggest some ways to achieve those goals (e.g., help suggest experiments or metrics/measurements).  The more concrete you can make the question, the better the chances someone can answer.  Of course, if you don't actually have any reseac goals right now and you just want to know in general whether there's a systematic way to do it, you probably won't be able to make the question any more concrete; in that case you can disregard this comment.